# Installing mayavi with pip - No module named vtkCommonCorePython

Tags: python, installation, pip, vtk, mayavi

I want to install mayavi using pip.

**Situation**

- Mac with OS 10.11.1
- Homebrew installed python version 2.7.10
- Homebrew installed VTK5 version 5.10.1 (built --with-qt)
- For Python to find the bindings of VTK5 I used

  echo /usr/local/opt/vtk5/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk5.pth

**Problem**

I run the following command

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/vtk5/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/vtk5/include" mayavi
```

, which results in

```
ImportError: No module named vtkCommonCorePython
```

at the end.

**Previous attempts**

Before this, I used VTK 6.3 (installed with homebrew and uninstalled afterwards)
for which

```
pip install mayavi
```

resulted in

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I do not particularly care which VTK version I need to use, any solution enabling me to install mayavi will help.